# LDAP search text field that contains exact match of comma separated values [in python]

Tags: python, ldap

I am using python ldap3 library but I think this is not very specific to the package, the problem I am having is I have a field on ldap I need to search on, say

"extraDivs" has values like "AAA,BBB"

[image]

I cannot use this filter `"extraDivs=*{}*".format(code)`, problem is that if my div is "AA", it also matches "AAA", which I don't want.

How do I create the filter that matches exact values in side the comma separated string? Is it even possible?

Comment: Just to understand a bit clearer. You have a string which is comma seperated, and you want to search this string to see if  `AA` matches a value between two commas, but it cannot match `AAA`?

Comment: @PacketLoss yes correct

Comment: Could you just split the string and search for an exact match in the list? `'AA' in extraDivs.split(',')` ?

Comment: Please note, the extraDivs field is in LDAP, I want to search against this field

Comment: Could you provide some more code specifically on defining the field etc. Would make testing much easier.

Comment: Added the field definition from ldap

Comment: If you don't want wildcard behaviour why are you using a wildcard?

Comment: I don't know what else I can use, not a ldap expert here.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with LDAP filtering. You'll have to match `(extraDivs=*AA*)` and then, in a post-processing step, filter out `AAA`